# C# - Issue with file move over shared folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Scenario:**
I have a client & server architecture. Client program captures multiple displays connected to a machine and saves as jpg file in a folder. The minimum speed is 5 images per second per display. Same folder is shared over network. 
I have a windows service running on a server grade machine which pulls all the files as soon as it is created in the shared folder. These files are rendered in a browser through asp.net page through an img tag like live streaming. These files are also used to make a video later.

**Problem:**
Once in 8-10 days I see a slow down of file copy process where the client machine stacks more than 30,000 images in the folder but server could not pull it for some reason.
With the help of Red-Gate profiler I could find that only file copy process was stuck and could not move the file. After some time server pull process covered all the lag & came on track. To access file I am using Fast Directory Enumerator. More info here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38959/A-Faster-Directory-Enumerator

Initially we tried push implementation where client was pushing the images to server folder but got similar performance issue more frequently. 
I confirmed that there was no network connectivity issue as well as CPU utilization was low when the process lagged. I have also handled case where a file is being accessed by another process due to which it could not be moved.

1. What could be the reason for this delay?
2. Is there any other best option to move the files to server?